# Android kotlin Cannot Generated Signed Bundle/APK. Getting error : Type a.a.a.a.a is defined multiple times

Tags: android, kotlin, zoom-sdk

I have search many times to solve this error. My apps going well when build with no signed but it getting error when build Signed Bundle/APK. I used zoom meeting android SDK in my project with module name mobilertc and commonlib. i have included multidex depedencies and try to delete .gradle file then invalidate/restart android, but it still get error like this :

Type a.a.a.a.a is defined multiple times: C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\android-zoomsdk\mobilertc\build.transforms\135bfa37c7ff11bc18f4ecf26c77ccbe\jetified-mobilertc-runtime\classes.dex, C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\android -zoomsdk\app\build\intermediates\external_libs_dex\developmentRelease\mergeExtDexDevelopmentRelease\classes.dex

I need to generate my Signed Bundle/APK that used to upload to play store. I really appreciate your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like an obfuscation issue related to the zoom sdk. Therefore I suggest asking the question in zoom´s developer forum.

Comment: As @Traendy said, there's something with the **ZOOM SDK**, you need to add some `Proguard` rules, check this : https://devforum.zoom.us/t/zoom-sdk-doesnt-work-with-proguard-enabled/38085

Comment: thanks for the respon, i have posted my question on zoom developer forum. they said bcs proguard config but it still cannot solve.